# Why is this C program crashes on windows and works fine on linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, crash

I wrote a program to find the harmonic numbers

> *(the n-th **harmonic number** is the sum of the **reciprocals** of the first n **natural numbers**)*

of sequence of numbers. My program takes its input as command line arguments and prints the harmonic numbers in the table format. 
As an example This is how it works:

```
 C:\Users\EDDiE\c>har 10 30 5
      10 2.9289682539682538
      15 3.3182289932289937
      20 3.5977396571436819
      25 3.8159581777535068
      30 3.9949871309203906
```

> 10(**argv [1]**) = starting number,
>
> 30(**argv[2]**) = ending number,
>
> 5(**argv[3]**) = step to advance.

**In** my **windows 8** machine this program **crashes** **at** the number **43429**

Then I execute on [an online c compiler](http://goo.gl/E8uNZK) it is a linux environment ( "I think", I'm not a linux user ) And it works fine then.

Here is my program:

> har.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double harmonic(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int j;
    int start = 1, end = 10, step = 1;

    switch(argc) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        end = atoi(argv[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        start = atoi(argv[1]);
        end = atoi(argv[2]);
        break;
    case 4:
        start = atoi(argv[1]);
        end = atoi(argv[2]);
        step = atoi(argv[3]);
        break;
    }

    for (j = start; j <= end; j += step)
        printf("%7d %3.20g\n", j, harmonic(j));

    return 0;
}


double harmonic(int n)
{
    //double H;
    if (n == 1 || n == 0)
        return 1.0;
    else
        return (1.0 / (double) n) + harmonic(n - 1);

    //return H;
}
```

I need to know why this program crashes at windows environment.

Is there anything I need to modify in the code (or in my system)?

Comment: Since you're using recursion and this problem is platform-dependent and only occurs at a certain level of recursion it suggests that you are encountering a classic [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow). Try increasing the stack size.

Comment: The default process stack size in Linux is 8 MB, but on Windows it's only 1 MB. If your recursion runs deep enough you might get a stack overflow in Windows but not on Linux.

Comment: ... and the code as shown seems to inflict the stack space required by printf() onto every level of recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already been stated in the comments you're most probably experiencing a stack-overflow. There's hope though, your recursion can be transformed easily to an iteration as follows:

```
double harmonic(int n) {
  if(n == 0) return 1.0;
  double res = 0.0;
  while(n > 0) {
    res += (1.0 / (double) n);
    --n;
  }
  return res;
}
```

This way your program will work for big `n`.